# Accessing the max element from a list in another class - JAVA

Tags: java

for educational purposes I am trying to understand how to access a list's maximum element(originally in class B) (in this case from a Double list) through another class e.g class A. The list is used in a different class in which elements are added to it (e.g class C). However, when I add something like this to my class A to access my Max element, it does not seem to work: // help is appreciated :) and the error I usually get is  noSuchElementException

just a method of class A

```
void printMax () {

    B b = new B();
    Double result;
    result = Collections.max(b.array);
    System.out.println("MAX:" +result);
    }
```

here is my class B:

```
public class B {

public ArrayList<Double> array;

    B() {           
        array = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
                    int i;          
            for(i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("Doubles:" +array.get(i));

            }                           
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new B().doSomething();
    }

}
```

Here is my class C that adds to my ArrayList.

```
Class C {
public String line;


C () {  

}

public void linePicker() {

    B b = new B();          

    Scanner dScanner = new Scanner(line);
    while (dScanner.hasNext()) {
        if (dScanner.hasNextDouble()) {             
            b.array.add(dScanner.nextDouble());                                             
            break;
        } else {
            dScanner.next();
        }
    }       
    dScanner.close();

    b.doSomething();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new C().linePicker();
}

}
```

Comment: Where is class A being instantiated? I feel like you provided half the code, and it wasn't the half we needed.

Comment: Also, please include the full stack trace and indicate (e.g. via comments) which lines are the ones it refers to.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? I'm not convinced it's failing where you think it is.

Comment: The lines it points to is:  result = Collections.max(b.array); and   new A().printMax();(in the main)

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the javadocs to track return values and exception handling!

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadocs ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29)), it throws that exception when the Collection is empty. You initialize b.array, but haven't added to it yet before calling max().

Comment: That is what is perplexing me as the printMax() method is supposed to run after the list has been stocked..

Comment: None of the code you posted inserts a Double to your Collection.

Comment: Your program isn't outputting anything when doSomething() is called, which proves that array is empty, thus the exception.